# Dragging is flickery when containment's overflow property is scroll?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

**I want to make an element draggable in a fixed area that has its overflow property set to scroll.**

If I use `containment` property in the draggable element, then the dragging downwards or to the right becomes flickery.
What I mean by this is that when the edge of dragged element hits the edge of the container, it does not scroll until the cursor hits the edge as well.

I can prevent this by not setting the containment property on the draggable setup. However when I drag to the left or top, the dragged element becomes invisible by being dragged to some negative x/y position.

**How can I prevent the flicker when using containment property?**

Plunkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/pmGO6lswaSJtwMSC1bXe?p=preview

```
#container {
    border:1px solid red; 
    min-height:3in;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin-left:120px;
}

.widget {
    background: beige;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px; width:100px;
}



<div id="container">
     <div class="widget"></div>
</div>



$(function(){
  $('.widget').draggable({
    scroll:true,
    containment: '#container' // comment out to see the smoothness on bottom/right edge drags
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this

```
$(function(){
  $('.widget').draggable({
    scroll:true,
    drag:function(evt, obj) {
      if (obj.position.top < 0) {
        obj.position.top = 0;
      }
      if (obj.position.left < 0) {
        obj.position.left = 0;
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Inspired by answer to this question ->  [jQuery UI draggable, stop drag but let dragging the other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899821/jquery-ui-draggable-stop-drag-but-let-dragging-the-other-way)